# How to protect my system, which runs the Sesame triplestore, from injections when querying using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, code-injection, sesame

Title says it all. Is there something equivalent to SQL's prepared statements?

Comment: Not as such. There are engines, like my employer's [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), that offer differently privileged endpoints, for read-only, read-write, etc., which privileges may vary with the user. Virtuoso also supports SPARQL-in-SQL, so you can make all queries happen in SQL, which lets you use prepared statements in the client tool, which can connect via ODBC, JDBC, dotNET, etc....  Complex answer, but it's a complex puzzle!

Comment: In Apache Jena [`ParameterizedSparqlString`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) and the `QueryBuilder` support this. But only from Java code afaik. In RDF4J, there is also a way to prepare queries: https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/repository/#preparing-and-reusing-queries - I can't say if internally injection test are done. Jeen Broekstra will most likely give you the answer soon here

Comment: (not a complete solution) For SPARQL, query and updates are different languages. A query(only) endpoint will only accept queries. An update injected into a query will be a syntax error.

Comment: @AndyS So worst case scenario my server throws some exception?

Comment: Arbitrary injection into a query can make the query (very, very) slow. System exceptions might happen (e.g. out of memory).  Injecting updates actions should cause an HTTP response of 400 (Bad request) - its a bad syntax query.

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you actually using Sesame? If so, you should really consider upgrading to RDF4J - Sesame was discontinued more than 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

(assuming you are using a recent version of RDF4J, and not Sesame)

To prevent vulnerabilities due to injection, a simple approach is to use a [prepared query](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/repository/#preparing-and-reusing-queries), and use `Query#setBinding` to inject actual user input values into your query. For example:

```java
// some input keyword to inject
String keyword = "foobar";

TupleQuery query = con.prepareTupleQuery(
       "PREFIX ex: <htt://example.org/> " 
     + "SELECT ?document WHERE { ?document ex:keyword ?keyword . }");

// inject the input keyword
query.setBinding("keyword", factory.createLiteral(keyword));

// execute the query
TupleQueryResult result = query.evaluate();
```

For more advanced control, RDF4J also has a [SparqlBuilder](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/sparqlbuilder/), a fluent API for creating SPARQL queries in Java, for this purpose. For example:

```java
String keyword = "foobar";

Prefix ex = SparqlBuilder.prefix("ex", Rdf.iri("http://example.org/"));
Variable document = SparqlBuilder.var("document");

SelectQuery query = Queries.SELECT().prefix(ex).select(document)
        .where(GraphPatterns.tp(document, ex.iri("keyword"), Rdf.literalOf(keyword));
```